# Angular JS compare 2 objects and move non-matching key value pairs into new object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hi I was just wondering if there is an easy way, or if there is any well explained examples in how to compare 2 objects in angular when you know the order of the key value pairs is going to be the same in both objects. It would just be the case of if any items are different just move the different one  out into a new object.

I am aware that there is the likes of `angular.equals(obj1, obj2)` which will return a boolean. However what I would be interested in if the two objects are different take the pairs and put them in a new object.

If any know a quick and easy way of doing this it would be of much help.

Thanks

Comment: I believe you are looking for a deep object diff tool, like [this](https://github.com/flitbit/diff).

Answer (score 1):

Compare two identical objects for changes and put changed key value pairs in to new object.

```
$scope.individualItemsToUpdate = {};
        angular.forEach($scope.objectWithChanges, function (value, key) {
            if (value != $scope.originalObject[key]) {
                $scope.individualItemsToUpdate[key] = value;

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

When you say you know the order of the keys does this mean you could have a list of them? If so you could do:

```
var keys = ['val1', 'val2', 'val3'],
    difference = {};

keys.map(function(key){
  if (obj1[key] && !obj2[key]) {
    difference.push(obj1[key]);
  } else if (obj1[key] && !obj2[key]) {
    difference.push(obj1[key]);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks I came up with something similar using the obj[key] approach :)